# Multiple initializer values in Flash Builder

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe, flash-builder

Finally decided to try Flash Builder rather than FlashDevelop and got caught up on my very first app. I'm building a AIR app and downloaded the latest SDK and installed it in the Flash Builder path.

When I add a few simple items they all get errors. I added this code:

```
<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout paddingLeft="10" paddingTop="10"/>        
    <s:Label id="myLabel" text="Some text stuff I typed."/>
    <s:Button click="myLabel.text='Some stuff the button typed'"/>        
</s:layout>
```

And I get an error on each spark item (except layout) that says:
In initializer for 'layout', multiple initializer values for target type spark.layouts.supportClasses.LayoutBase.

I've searched google with no real results. Does anyone know what this error is telling me? Is there a problem with the SDK installation? I followed install instructions from a Lynda.com vid.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure which Flex SDK or Flash builder version you are working with but in version 4 try this,

```
<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout paddingLeft="10" paddingTop="10"/>
</s:layout>       
<s:Label id="myLabel" text="Some text stuff I typed."/>
<s:Button click="myLabel.text='Some stuff the button typed'"/>
```

You create the components after the closing layout tag not inside it.

Comment: Sorry, I cut and pasted a version where I was trying it inside the layout tag, but initialy I had it set like yours and got the same error. In fact, that's why I tried it inside the layout tag and inside the VerticalLayout tag without success.